# How to add a check box in views exposed filter

Tags: views

I need to add a checkbox in an exposed filter to strip left and right space of a value entered by user, i.e: I have email field on the basis of email filtering the user some time user add left or right extra space. I need a handler or plugins globally which is applied for all text field. If the somehow global implementation is critical so, on the specific field is also ok.

Comment: Sanjay welcome to stackexhange.  Adding anything to any form requires most probably usage of `hook_form_alter` in a custom module.  What have you done so far ?  Question is not clear.  What do you want happening after the form is submitted ? Please give example code that you have tried and example output you expect.

Comment: Thanks Giorgosk quick reply. Let me explain I have created a views for filter user on the basis of 'First name, Last name, Username, E-mail' etc. Now my requirement is if admin by mistake enter email id " test@gmail.com" or " test@gmail.com ", should be result come same as when I search with out space.

So, I want to a checkbox in views globally through which is attached with textfield exposed filter i.e: title, email, first name, last name etc. If checkbox checked in views then space will be trim while search. I hope now the requirement is clear. If any please let me know. Thanks :)

Comment: Please improve the actual question above with a clear example.

Comment: @GiorgosK
I need a checkbox in highlighted area. If it's checked then we need to add trim in query and I need for textfield. Please have a look in screenshot https://drive.google.com/file/d/1gJR9zzD86OoPtmiF_Ksb-dof6N-Tmr8M/view.

I need a checkbox same as 'Remember the last selection' option and it's available for all textfield.